# Git rebase leaves uncommited files between steps?

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-rebase

```
>git rebase <parent>
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: <First Change>
Applying: <Second Change>
.git/rebase-apply/patch:20: trailing whitespace.

warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        <some exiting project file file>
        <another existing project file>
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Patch failed at 0002 <Second change>
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
```

I'm used to resolving `CONFLICT` files during merge or rebase. But this situation has me puzzled. There is no CONFLICT, is just that second change cannot be applied because there are files that would be overwritten, which makes no sense to me. These are all existing files which are tracked.  `git status` before the rebase shows no pending adds, the files show themselves correctly in `git log -- <some exiting project file file>`. The `<First Change>` does not touch these files. The `<Second Change>` modifies them, but rebase somehow sees the patch as an overwrite.

Any explanation for this mystery, any suggestion how to tackle this problem?

`git version 2.14.1.windows.1`

Comment: And to make it completely baffling, one minute later the rebase applies clean. It failed 4 times before, and yesterday as well (it failed several times, then it applied). Always fails at the same step, same files.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion that is is caused by interaction between VS keeping open file handles and git. An aggravating factor appears to be having a gulp:serve task running while js/ts/css files are being checked in/checked out/branch changed/origin pull etc. I have also noticed access denied errors with security descriptors of the files being completely busted (eg. cannot take ownership of file not even as local system). Is sad to see NTFS metadata handling in such a poor state, but the conclusion  for me is: close VS when working with git. Or use vim and msbuild from command line, which is way more relaible, and easier to use.. but I digress.